# Trying to figure out how to display the length of each word in a string separated by commas in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I'm implementing a quote into a table that has multiple modifications to the string..Trying to figure out how to display the length of each word in a string separated by commas in PHP? In this case it should be displayed in the table like (4,2,3,2,...).

Also, I'm almost certain I don't need to create multiple functions for each modification but I am running low on time and had to make do.

I know this code looks like trash but I've only gotten into PHP/HTML 2 weeks ago..First question here so bear with me.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>


 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Need Help!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <center>
  <h1></h1>
  <table border = "1">
    <tr>
        <td><b>Modification</b></td>
        <td><b>Description</b></td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Original</td>
        <td><?php orig(quote) ;?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Capitilize first letter of each word</td>
        <td><?php upCase(newquote);?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Displays the word length for each word seperated by commas</td>
        <td><?php ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Randomly shuffles each word in the quote</td>
        <td><?php ?></td>
    </tr>

    <?php


        function orig($quote){
        $quote = " There are only two ways to live your life. 
        One is as though nothing is a miracle. 
        The other is as though everything is a miracle. <p>
        -Albert Einstein";
        echo $quote;
        }
        function upCase($newquote){
        $quote = " There are only two ways to live your life. 
        One is as though nothing is a miracle. 
        The other is as though everything is a miracle. <p>
        -Albert Einstein";
        $newquote = ucwords($quote);
        echo $newquote;
        }

    ?>


    </table>
    </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part is to split the text into words, there are various ways ( `explode()` by spaces, regex's which split by white space, this just uses `str_word_count()`).

Then it builds an array of the length of each of the words and `implodes()` the result...

```
function wordLengths($quote =  "There are only two ways to live your life.
        One is as though nothing is a miracle.
        The other is as though everything is a miracle. <p>
        -Albert Einstein"){
    $lengths = [];
    foreach ( str_word_count($quote, 1) as $word ) {
        $lengths[] = strlen($word);
    }
    echo implode(",", $lengths);
}
```

called by

```
wordLengths();
```

gives

```
5,3,4,3,4,2,4,4,4,3,2,2,6,7,2,1,7,3,5,2,2,6,10,2,1,7,1,7,8
```

Also your existing code contains quite a few errors, try adding...

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the start of the script to help show problems as they come up.

Comment: Thank you so much, Nigel. I really appreciate it!

Comment: One more thing, I recently edited my post. Would I do a similar process for randomly shuffling the letters in each word?

Comment: Please don't add new questions to existing posts.  If you have a new question, then ask a new question.

Comment: 10-4 sorry about that. Pretty new here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's OK, happy to help, it also means that if I go off and do something else then you will get help from others rather than waiting for me to get back tomorrow.

Comment: I rolled the question back.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
        <td>Displays the word length for each word seperated by commas:</td>
        <td>
        <?php
            $string_lengths = [];
            foreach(explode(" ","abcd defghi jk lmnop q rstuv") as $each_String){
               $string_lengths[] = strlen($each_String); 
            }
            echo implode(",",$string_lengths);
        ?>
       </td>
</tr>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Displays the word length for each word seperated by commas: 4,6,2,5,1,5
```